# Using the snap node with the Voronoi texture

Tags: materials

I know that you can use a snap (vector math) node to "pixelate" an image by plugging it into a vector input of an image texture node, but instead of square pixels, I'd like the shape of the pixel to be dictated by a voronoi crackle texture. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'Position' output of  *Voronoi* texture returns the location of the cell's feature-point in each cell, and your image can be sampled there:

[image]

The 'UV' *Texture Coordinate* is a default, so optional. But it's nice to know where you are.

(Incidentally, if you're being lazy, you can use this to sample a regular rectangular grid,too,  by setting the *Voronoi*'s 'Randomness' to 0.)

Comment: Saturday speed run :) Notification - someone is at answering process still welcomed :) BTW any chance to avoid thing line in between? Thank you

Comment: Hi, @vklidu! I was wondering about that, too.  It seems to be an EEVEE artefact. Cycles doesn't show it.. some sort of clamping / default? When 2 distances to feature-point are nearly equal, instead of choosing one or the other, the texture chooses neither, and not even a consistent neither.  This could be reportable?

Comment: wow....just changing some variables and so many different effects...amazing!! +1